# Emitting the results of a session window every X minutes

Tags: apache-flink

I've implemented a Flink processor that aggregates events into sessions and then writes them to a sink. Now I'd like extend it so that I can get the number of concurrent sessions every five minutes.

The events coming into my system are on the form:

```
{
  "SessionId": "UniqueUUID",
  "Customer": "CustomerA",
  "EventType": "EventTypeA",
  [ ... ]
}
```

And a single session usually contains several events of different EventTypes. I then aggregate the events into sessions by doing the following in Flink.

```
DataStream<Session> sessions = events
                .keyBy((KeySelector<HashMap, String>) event -> (String) event.get(Field.SESSION_ID))
                .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time.minutes(5)))
                .trigger(SessionProcessingTimeTrigger.create())
                .aggregate(new SessionAggregator())
```

Each session is the emitted (by the SessionProcessingTimeTrigger) when an event with a specific EventType is processed ("EventType":"Session.Ended"). And finally the stream is sent to a sink and written Kafka.

Now I want to write a similar Flink processor but instead of only emitting a session once it is finished, I instead want to emit all sessions every 5 minutes in order to keep track of how many concurrent session we have every 5 minutes.
So in a sense I guess what I want is a SessionWindow that also emits it's contents at regular intervals without purging the content.

I'm stumped on how to accomplish this in Flink and are therefore looking for some aid.

Comment: I would try to remove the `trigger` function and add another window of 5 minutes after the `aggregate` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want a Flink window to emit results at non-default times, you can do this by implementing a custom Trigger. You trigger just needs to return FIRE each time a 5-minute-long timer fires, in addition to its original logic. You'll want to register this timer when the first event is assigned to a window, and again every time the timer fires.

In the case of session windows this can be more complex because of the manner in which session windows are merged. But I believe that in the case of processing time session windows what I've outlined above will work.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to do just this, but the problem happens when windowing those emitted events, they come with the original event timestamp and not the emission time.
Is there nay workaround to it that i am missing?